# Get 500 error when deploy a .NET Core Web App to IIS server by Azure Pipelines

Tags: iis, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I'm using `AzureDevOps` as the `CI&CD` tool os my project. And I used the template called `IIS website deployment`. I've done the configuration and it runs well. It can deploy successfully. But I can just get a 500 error when I view it.

Port 80 (There's no site on it):

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Port 8000 (I deployed my site and opened the firewall access):
I can't get any page like 500 or so, there's only an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` on the browser.

Here is the screenshot from the destination folder where the code been build
[image: Screenshot]

web.config.xml
[image: web.config.xml]

Is there any code I missed in Startup.cs or Program.cs? I leave them as default.

Comment: Show the full error page.

Comment: How to show full error page?

Comment: 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Please show what's in your site's root folder.

Comment: And please try executing `dotnet ./yourdll.dll` to test if your app can be started successfully.

Comment: Is there anything like a start scripts to run the app in the IIS console?

Comment: Then please reveal contents of your web.config. 500.19 indicates configuration errors.

Comment: It can start successfully with `dotnet ./project.dll`

Answer (score 1):

To run ASP.NET Core app behind IIS, you need to install the hosting bundle first.

The bundle installs the .NET Core Runtime, .NET Core Library, and the ASP.NET Core Module. The module allows ASP.NET Core apps to run behind IIS.

Download it here:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/permalink/dotnetcore-current-windows-runtime-bundle-installer

For more info, reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle

After installing this hosting bundle, try run `dotnet ./yourdll.dll` to test if your .NET Core app can be started directly and ready to handle HTTP requests. By default, an ASP.NET Core app will start and listen to port 5000.

When your app is ready, deploy it to your IIS folder. Write you web.config like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\YOUR_DLL.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

And try to access it from IIS.

Comment: It doesn't work from my personal computer. It can use inside of the VM

Comment: Chrome returns an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error when I'm trying to browse my website

Comment: Did you follow the answer? Install the hosting bundle, and then install IIS, and then publish to the IIS?

Comment: I restarted the server after I installed the hosting bundle. I used Azure Pipelines to publish it to the server

Comment: And you mentioned that IIS returnes you `500` error. Please make it clear: Is the problem that you couldn't connect to IIS? Or is the problem that you can connect to IIS but failed? Those are different problems. You need to be clear about what you are trying to solve. The answer I posted is for `500` error after deployment. Not related to any network area.